# Need help with string manipulation please

Tags: c#, asp.net

If my string has values as :-

```
myString = "Good Morning,Good Night";
```

and I want to reverse the values in it like as follows:-

I want the final values in the myString as:-

```
myString = "Good Night,Good Morning";
```

How do I achieve this? Any help will be appreaciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: please be more specific about what you are reversing? is it "{a},{b}" => "{b},{a}", or "Good {a},Good {b}" => "Good {b},Good {a}", or what?

Comment: @Marc :: I just want "Good Night" to appear before "Good Morning" on my page when I print this string. Please note the spaces in between. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Serenity in that case, just hard-code "Good Night,Good Morning". Otherwise, you need to be specific - for example, what happens when the text is "Good Night,Average Morning" - is it "Average Morning,Good Night" or is it "Good Morning,Average Night". You haven't defined the problem...

Comment: @Marc:: The text isn't good morning or good night. It will be different everytime. I just want that the text AFTER the "comma" is displayed firstly..like it gets reversed..um not sure how to explain anymore clearly :/

Comment: There we go; *now* you've defined it. Previously it was ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
string myString = "Good Morning,Good Night";
string[] subStrings = myString.Split(',');
myString = string.Join(",", subStrings.Reverse());
```

Or if you like to write these as one liners:

```
myString = string.Join(",", myString.Split(',').Reverse());
```

Comment: I tried that. It says this now :The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You must be on .NET 3.5. Add a call to ToArray() after the Reverse() and you should be set

Comment: @Serenity - I verified it now by copy/pasting the code from my answer, and it works as intended. You must have done a mistake somewhere. Sure you have written "," and not ','?

Comment: Why does using single vs double-quotes break this?

Comment: Because `String.Join` takes a `string` for it's first argument, not a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

`var newString = string.Join(",", myString.Split(',').Reverse());`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you're trying to do is split the string on commas. Something like this:

```
        string myString = "Good Morning,Good Night";
        string[] split = myString.Split(',');
        myString = split[1] + ',' + split[0];
```

Comment: giving Index out of bounds error on this line : myString = split[1] + ',' + split[0];

Comment: It was some silly mistake of mine that caused that error. Its working fine. Thanks! :)